# add an additional parameter to an observable response

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following code

```
    getFileAsync(fieldFiles: Array<FileFields>): Observable<Array<UploadFile>> {
        const files = Array<UploadFile>();
        const downloads = Array<Observable<any>>();
        fieldFiles.forEach(file => {
            downloads.push(FileHelper.downloadFile(file.file_id));
        });
        forkJoin(downloads).subscribe({
            next: filesData => {
                console.log(filesData)
                fieldFiles.forEach((file, index) => {
                    const fileData = filesData[index];
                    files.push({
                        uid: file.file_id,
                        name: file.filename,
                        url: fileData ? window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([fileData.data], {type: file.contentType})) : require('../../../assets/images/file.png'),
                        size: file.size,
                        type: file.contentType,
                    })
                })
            },
            error: () => {}
        });
    }
```

Basically, I have a list of file, and I would like to download them one by one:

I use `FileHelper.downloadFile` which return an http observable

```
        const downloads = Array<Observable<any>>();
        fieldFiles.forEach(file => {
            downloads.push(FileHelper.downloadFile(file.file_id));
        });
```

Then, I use forkJoin(downloads) to send the request and get the responses.
But, I would like to use `concatMap` instead and download the file one by one.

But the problem is, the http request do not return the file id, so I need a way to know what id is currently the one that is beeing loaded. Something like this :

```
        const downloads = Array<Observable<any>>();
        fieldFiles.forEach(file => {
            const fileId = file.file_id;
            downloads.push(FileHelper.downloadFile(fileId));
        });
        concatMap(downloads).subscribe({
            next: (filesData, fileId) => {}
```

Is there a way to add this variable and "bind" it to the observable of the http request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use observable's map operator to transform it into an object with both id and data. Something like this:

```
    const downloads = Array<Observable<any>>();
    fieldFiles.forEach(file => {
        const fileId = file.file_id;
        downloads.push(FileHelper.downloadFile(fileId).map((x) => ({ id: fileId, data: x}));
    });
    concatMap(downloads).subscribe({
        next: (x) => { 
           // x.data 
           // x.id
         });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, It looks exactly what I would like, but I have `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'` when I try your code

Comment: ok I used 
`downloadsObs.push(FileHelper.downloadFile(file.file_id).pipe(map((resp) => ({ fileId: file.file_id, response: resp}))));` and it looks nice thank you